# insert into temp table using Cross Apply?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, temp-tables

I want to create a temp table and insert values based on the select. The query doesn't execute, What am i missing ? I eventually want to loop thru the temp table

```
Create Table #temp (ID varchar(25),Source_Id varchar(25),Processed   varchar(25), Status varchar(25),Time_Interval_Min varchar(25))
Insert into #temp   
Select t.*
From
   (SELECT DISTINCT source_id 
    FROM Activity_WorkLoad) t1
    CROSS APPLY 
   (
    SELECT TOP 1
      aw.ID,
      Source_Id 
      ,Processed 
      ,Status 
      ,Time_Interval_Min
   FROM [dbSDS].[dbo].[Activity_WorkLoad] aw
   JOIN [dbSDS].[dbo].[SDA_Schedule_Time] st ON aw.SDA_Resource_ID = st.ID
   WHERE aw.Source_Id = t1.Source_Id AND aw.Status = 'Queued'
   ORDER BY Processed DESC  
   )t
```

Comment: "The query doesn't execute": what error do you got?

Comment: You are selecting `t.*`, but `t` only has 1 column in it and you arent specifying which column to put it into.  Pretty sure that this query doesnt do what you are actually wanting to do.  Why dont you ask that question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `cross apply`, you still need an alias:

```
Insert into #temp   (id, source_id, processed, status, time_interval_min)
    Select tt.*
    From (SELECT DISTINCT source_id 
          FROM Activity_WorkLoad
         ) t CROSS APPLY 
         (SELECT TOP 1 aw.ID, Source_Id, Processed, Status, Time_Interval_Min
          FROM [dbSDS].[dbo].[Activity_WorkLoad] aw JOIN 
               [dbSDS].[dbo].[SDA_Schedule_Time] st
               ON aw.SDA_Resource_ID = st.ID
          WHERE aw.Source_Id = t.Source_Id AND aw.Status = 'Queued'
          ORDER BY Processed DESC  
        ) tt;
```

I also assume that you want results from the second subquery, not the first, because the first does not have enough columns.